# How to set levels for a vector where first 8 characters vary?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, levels

I have time data that I am attempting to change into factor variables "AM" and "PM"

Problem is the first 8 or so characters vary before getting to the am or pm. So how do I set these levels when this is the case? Here is my data

```
structure(c(7L, 1L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 3L, 
5L, 8L, 2L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 24L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("4/12/2016 1:00:00 AM", 
"4/12/2016 1:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 10:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 10:00:00 PM", 
"4/12/2016 11:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 11:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM", 
"4/12/2016 12:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 2:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 2:00:00 PM", 
"4/12/2016 3:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 3:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 4:00:00 AM", 
"4/12/2016 4:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 5:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 5:00:00 PM", 
"4/12/2016 6:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 6:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 7:00:00 AM", 
"4/12/2016 7:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 8:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 8:00:00 PM", 
"4/12/2016 9:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 9:00:00 PM"), class = "factor")
```

I am doing this so I can order the data on a graph.. [image: average_intensities]
As you can see the data is currently ordered alphabetically and I would like it to be ordered by numerically alphabetically. Any help would be appreciated!! Thank you

Comment: Why not use date/time type (`POSIXct`) and format x-axis to show in hours?

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend using factors or characters for dates, because the information is really different and dates are handled quite nicely by `ggplot2`.

It would probably be better to use `lubridate`: in order to both parse the dates and extract meaningful information from them.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- tibble(
  date = lubridate::dmy_hms(
    c("4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 1:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 2:00:00 AM", 
      "4/12/2016 3:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 4:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 5:00:00 AM", 
      "4/12/2016 6:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 7:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 8:00:00 AM", 
      "4/12/2016 9:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 10:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 11:00:00 AM", 
      "4/12/2016 12:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 1:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 2:00:00 PM", 
      "4/12/2016 3:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 4:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 5:00:00 PM", 
      "4/12/2016 6:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 7:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 8:00:00 PM", 
      "4/12/2016 9:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 10:00:00 PM", "4/12/2016 11:00:00 PM"
    )),
  am_or_pm = ifelse(lubridate::am(date), "AM", "PM"),
  x = rnorm(24))
```

What is extra nice with `lubridate` is that it will do a lot of work for you, like work out how years, months, days and times are specified in the character strings that you provide it. Also, t comes with a lot of useful functions, like `am`, that will tell you if it's morning or afternoon! That `tibble` could be then used in a plot:

```
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, x, color = am_or_pm)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_bw()
```

that would look like this

[image: Scatterplot with times]

Comment: Okay thank you. This is Great however it looks like you are creating a new data frame with the tibble. I already have a data frame and the ActivityHoursII (date) is just a category. This is only a problem because I have another category (AverageIntensity) that I am trying to plot on the y axis

Comment: You could just convert to dates the column containing the dates ? `dat$date <- lubridate::hmy_hms(dat$date)`